# How to determine distribution and expected value?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am struggling with part **ii)** of the following question.

[image: Probability distribution.]

How do I determine the distribution of $s$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The domain of $s$ is given by $D=[0,3]$. Now for $x\in D$ we have
$$
P(s\le x) = P(0.003p^2\le x) = P\left(p\le\sqrt{\frac{x}{0.003}}\right)
$$